# Crashes when using Union and Pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination, union

```
$medias = DB::connection('oracle').....
                   
$materials = DB::connection('oracle').....
                     
$union = $materials->union($medias);

 //pagination    
$page = Request::get('page', 1);
$paginate = 50;

$offSet = ($page * $paginate) - $paginate;
$itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($union, $offSet, $paginate, true);
$union = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, count($union), $paginate, $page);

return view('ReceiveMedia.index', compact('union'));
```

When running it I get an error like this

Error :

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
> array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

I searched the solution, I get like this

```
$union = $materials->union($medias)->get()->toArray();
```

But, it keeps me getting an error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

I'm so frustrated about this. Please if you know a solution would be to tell me

Comment: Laravel 5 provides a [pagination with query builder results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination#usage) , why are you trying to build your own Paginator?  Does `$union->paginate($paginate, ['*'], 'page', $page);` not work?

Comment: It will also get an error :  ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns Position. That's because union and pagination can't be combined properly

Comment: Union and pagination work fine together, you just need to make sure you end up with the same number of select columns in both queries. They also need to match the same data type. If both is correct you won't get this [error](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01789.php)